# Facing SSL issue suddenly while calling razorpay api

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, razorpay

I am working on a  Razorpay payment gateway integration My API was working fine but suddenly I am started getting the error:

> **Unable to get local issuer certificate**

This error can be resolved in postman by disabling SSL certificate verification.  But I can't able to figure out the original solution for this error.  Also this error appears on my Java application while using razorpay-api on the below code.

```
orderResponse = razorpay.Orders.create(orderRequest);
jsonNode = RazorpayUtils.mapper.readTree(orderResponse.toString());
            if (jsonNode.get("status").textValue().equals("created")) {
                System.out.println("Response of order api");
                response.setRazorpayOrderID(jsonNode.get("id").textValue());
                response.setRazorpayOrderAmount(jsonNode.get("amount").asInt());
                response.setOrderRecieptID(jsonNode.get("receipt").textValue());
                response.setRazorpayOrderStatus(jsonNode.get("status").textValue());
                response.setRazorpayCurrencyCode(jsonNode.get("currency").textValue());
                System.out.println("Response of Razorpay Order API." + response);
                return response;
            }
```

and facing below error.

```
com.razorpay.RazorpayException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.razorpay.ApiUtils.processRequest(ApiUtils.java:145)
    at com.razorpay.ApiUtils.postRequest(ApiUtils.java:62)
    at com.razorpay.ApiClient.post(ApiClient.java:40)
    at com.razorpay.OrderClient.create(OrderClient.java:14)
    at com.razorpayImp.services.OrderServiceImpl.createOrder(OrderServiceImpl.java:44)
    at com.razorpayImp.controllers.OrderController.createOrder(OrderController.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

So how to get this local issuer certificate to resolve this SSL certificate issue?

**Note**:  I got this issue for the past 2 days previously the same code was working fine.

Comment: 1) Has SSL certificate got changed at Razorpay end? 2) Do you have the root CAs on your computer trusting the razorpay SSL? 3) Any agents like `bluecoat` etc., intercepting SSL traffic ?

Comment: Hi @harshavmb the same code and the api  is working on my friend's machine. How to check whether i have the root CA on my machine?

Comment: If you have installed `openssl` like this.. `openssl s_client -connect <rajor-pay-host>:443`

Comment: @harshavmb
Not installed Open ssl in my machine

Comment: If you have Java 7 up installed you can get substantially the same data (though formatted differently) from `keytool -printcert -sslserver $host:$port` (you can omit :port if it's 443, which it usually is) (@harshavmb)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085
I'm using Java 8_321 version and I'm not using any SSL host or port.  I am just trying to hit Razorpay's API using tomcat.   Also as mentioned on post it was working two days before

Answer (score -1):

for PHP integration

Open  Razor-pay\libs\Requests-1.7.0\library\Requests\Transport\cURL.php

Comment out

```
/*
    if (isset($options['verify'])) {
    if ($options['verify'] === false) {
                curl_setopt($this->handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                curl_setopt($this->handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            }
            elseif (is_string($options['verify'])) {
                curl_setopt($this->handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $options['verify']);
            }
        }

        if (isset($options['verifyname']) && $options['verifyname'] === false) {
            curl_setopt($this->handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        }*/
```

and replace with

```
curl_setopt($this->handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($this->handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Basically, we have to switch off host verify / peer verify. started working again.

Comment: But now your communications are insecure. Don’t do this.